# Where and how host an AngularJs website?

Tags: angularjs, node.js, azure

I developed an AngularJS app, with a login page, register page and more basic functions. The app is developed in AngularJs and Firebase as database, it is very simple actually, the app runs in **http://localhost:8000/app/#/home** I need to run the server with a `npm start` to make the app works on the contrary it won't. It also needs `nodeJs`

My issue is: How and where could I host my website to a free/paid hosting? I don't know if there is some web hosting service which already contains `nodeJs`, `npm`.

Or

I need a guide of it. I have some sites hosted in Godaddy & Azure cloud. I don't know if those hosting providers offer what I need to make my app run. Please help with this issue. Thank a lot beforehand!

Comment: this isn't a code issue it's a host issue and is off-topic here. It is not hard to find node hosting online or ask your current hosts

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Azure WebApps with free pricing for NodeJS can satisfy your needs.

In Azure Portal, you can new an WebApp instance with NodeJS Starter Site for free pricing tier to deploy your AngularJS website.

The webapp has a public hostname(URL) for accessing. And you can add a CNAME record into DNS for your personal domain name.

If you need a database, the Azure WebApp supply a free 20MB SQL database as Website DB. Azure WebApp also support MySQL for the WebSite when creating a new instance.

Details for the steps how to create a nodejs webapp, please refer to https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/web-sites-nodejs-develop-deploy-mac/.

If you use Git or GitHub as source control, you can refer to https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/web-sites-publish-source-control/ to deploy the website into Azure WebApp.

About the pricing for Azure, please refer to https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/. The WebApp pricing is in the section "Azure App Service" of "Web+Mobile".

Any concern for Azure usage, please feel free to let me know.

Answer (score 0):

Easiest free way is to use heroku. You can set up an instance for free with the capability to deploy your node app and angular app there. It has scripts to run your app.

If you can install node in your godaddy server, you can install pm2 to run your node app on the server, and put all your angular directory in your regular web folder.